# Cypress Testing on Android Webview

Tags: android, testing, cypress

I have been using [Cypress Testing](https://www.cypress.io/) for automate navigation, and I would like to embed it in android to run it from a webview, maybe like:

```
getWebView(myWebView).evaluateJavascript(CypressJS, callback);
```

Any clue or advice is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: After search deeply, there is an open proposal for handle this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310 in which they pretend  to allow use cypress on a webview.  I'm preparing an alternative and then I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be useful for someone...
Originally the idea was to recreate the webview on an android project for inject JS code, but embed cypress is not available in an easy way, without have to package everything.

So, a close approach is to use electron, with a webview that has the same behaviour. In that case is possible to inject code and make tests using chai and mocha.

[Browser webview example](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/webview/browser)